# Is it possible to pass array in requestParams?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm building a page where people should be able to filter the content by multiple filter/values.
They should be able to share it by copying the url so the url should give information about current filter.

It will be optional parameters (requestParams) in ng2.
**But I'm wondering if it's possible to send array in requestParams like this** :

```js
this.router.navigate(['/heroes/12', { foo: ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'], test: 'youhou' }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to keep in mind people answers so I came up with the following answer :

I replaced array in url by a string with `.` between params' values. I completly own the params names and there values so no problem there. I just split/join the value when needed.

Why a `.`? Because it's a char that is not replaced in url and it makes url cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this.

Create a global valriable outside of scope, better in service and store your data in it. And in the end jut clear it when it's not required.

Or if you re using .ts inherit from some base controller, which contains that model.

Or create a service which will store this model and pass it into constructor.

Comment: I understand but what about the possibility to share the current filters ?

Comment: @jeremy why do you need this? this is angular, you are work here with models, controllers and services and all of this you can store in memory, without adding additional lines and parsing your URL's, because you just need to pass data from one controller to another, not to server side.

Comment: @jeremy so you are taken all data from server and the using client side filter, am I right?

Comment: @jeremy do you use Web Api or OData?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127159/discussion-between-borhunter-and-jeremy).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code? According to angular's documentation on [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Router-class.html#!#navigate-anchor), that's not how you should navigate.

Here is an example that should work, using [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html) to pass queryParams (which are in the url, and therefore, can be shared with the link):

```
//route is the current ActivatedRoute
this.router.navigate(['heroes', 12], {
    relativeTo: route, 
    queryParams: 
         { 
             foo: ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'],
             test: 'youhou' 
         }
);
```

Comment: They don't tell in the doc if we can use array but I'll try this. Thanks

Comment: I was talking about the fact that you pass a raw object as NavigationExtras, I don't think it should work. Plus the fact that an url is provided for navigateByUrl, not navigate.

Comment: Ok so I guess the answer to my question is no. Ihave so find some other way then. Thanks!

Comment: The example I provided should work and therefore allow you to pass array in queryParams (foo is an array)

Comment: Ok i'll try thin then and I'll let you know. Thanks.